# Error occured decoding the epsg code - 3857 (Web Mercator)

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, epsg

I'm trying to add the following wms service to QGIS using EPSG:3857 and get the following error:

Service (running on L/A/P/P geoserver):

```
http://66.228.57.208/geoserver/wms?tiled=true or non-cached http://66.228.57.208/geoserver/wms
```

Layer:

```
Carto_Basemap_WGS84WM layer group (presented in 3857 which contains ~ 8 layers all in 3857)
```

Error:

```
Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ServiceExceptionReport     version="1.3.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://66.228.57.208:80/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">   <ServiceException code="InvalidCRS">
  Error occurred decoding the espg code urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:3857
Database failure while creating a &apos;CoordinateReferenceSystem&apos; object for code &quot;EPSG:3857&quot;.
Connection is closed
```

Help!

Comment: I think some additional detail about where your data is stored would be useful.  Though the error initially is Decoding the EPSG Code, the lower part is more informative.  There, it says there was a database failure and the connection was closed.  This leads me to think it may be a problem with permissions or your connection string to your database.  Providing more detail about those aspects, may help.

Answer (score 1):

This error used to occur randomly in older versions of GeoServer (as in, on some machines it happened, on others never), but it should be fixed starting with 2.1.5 (yet to be released) and 2.2.0 (which is in RC3)